# List all applications under a specific job

Tags: upwork-api

I'm trying to List all applications that is under a specific job using upwork API ..

> applications that should return, contain the freelancers who I've sent invitation to, and the accepted the invitation but they aren't hired yet.

So i tried to use [List job applications as client](https://developers.upwork.com/?lang=node#contracts-and-offers_list-job-applications-as-client) giving it the `access_token, buyer_team_ref, job_key` , but all i get is this weird response

```
    "data": {
        "paging": {
            "offset": "0",
            "count": "0",
            "total": "0"
        },
        "scrolling": "",
        "applications": []
    }
}
```

that no applications is found in the `applications []`, while in my job at the website, i got applications, i got people who i hired them already and i can see them if i used [List engagements](https://developers.upwork.com/?lang=node#contracts-and-offers_list-engagements). but for applications i can't see them.

So i was wondering if i'm using the wrong API, or there is another way to retrieve them, or something wrong with the API itself :D ??

Answer (score 0):

If the people already hired, they are on a contract. Thus, List engagements is the right API. If you need more details about the difference between applications and contracts (engagements), feel free to contact our `Support Team` (https://support.upwork.com/)

Comment: No they aren't hired yet, they are at the step before hiring.